# Story in which the Earth's oxygen level is reduced so an Andean tribe can take over

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The story might have been in a collection of short stories or I read an excerpt of it. I read it in the 80s time frame. Possibly in Analog.

The idea of the story was that group of indigenous Andean (Inca) people introduce a bacterium that will deplete the atmospheric oxygen to a level that they are comfortable with, so that they can step in to govern while everyone else is gasping for breath. Written from a female Inca conspirator's point of view.

Comment: You have a nice general overview of the story here but could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) to see if there is anything else you can [edit] in?

Answer (score 8):

["The Cajamarca Project"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?48570), a novelette by [Charles L. Harness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_L._Harness), published in [*Analog Science Fiction/Science Fact*, February 1985](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?56873+c).

> "Antis . . . strange name," I said. "Not Spanish?"
>
> "No, *Indio*. In the *quechua* language *anti* means high mountain. Specifically Antis means the Andes. That's how the range was named."
>
> "So you're a native Andean?"
>
> "Yes. I was born in the Peruvian sierra, at five thousand meters—over fifteen thousand feet."
>
> "The air must be pretty thin."
>
> "About one-half atmosphere. But evolution has adapted us. Our lungs and hearts are bigger. We have twenty percent more blood than you lowlanders, and our blood is more viscous and has bigger cells. We are smaller, which means less body surface to lose heat. We have a fine time at fifteen thousand feet."
>
> "I don't think I would."
>
> "No, you'd get sick. They call it *el soroche*, altitude sickness. The slightest exertion would exhaust you. If you were very old or very young, you would probably die. Lowlander newborn risk brain damage at one-half atmosphere, caused by lack of oxygen." And now she studied me a moment. **"Do you have any idea what would happen if the air pressure in the lowlands all over the world were suddenly reduced to one-half atmosphere?"
>
>
> "I could guess. But tell me."
>
>
> "It would be just as I have described, only worse. The old and young die. The social fabric disintegrates. Terror, anarchy, chaos. Toward the end, only a few million of the strongest would be left. And then the mountain people would come down into the lowlands. They would inherit the destruction. They would come as hunters and gatherers of wild crops. They—only they—would possess the skills and the physiques needed for survival in such a world." Her eyes were burning.
>
>
> I gulped. She was dead serious. I stared at her, and I think my jaw must have dropped.**

This being a science fiction story, the Inca lady means business. She wants a designer bacillus:

> Back to Earth. The Administrator was talking to me. "The Señorita Doctor represents a group known as Atahualpa Associates—A.A.—with headquarters in Trujillo, Spain, and branches in Peru. She has presented a very interesting problem. A.A. wants a nitrogen-fixing bacillus."  
>
> I didn't get it. "There are plenty around already. They grow naturally, on practically all the legumes . . . soybeans, lespedeza, sweet clover, alfalfa."
>
> She shook her head. "Oh, that's quite true, of course." (She had a very faint accent.) "In fact, nitrogen-fixing microorganisms supply two-thirds of the nitrogen used world-wide by food crops. First, as I'm sure you know, the bacillus makes ammonia, which is quickly oxidized to the nitrate, and is then assimilated successively into nucleic acids, proteins, and chlorophyll. Unfortunately, each bacillus is specific to a given plant. We want a bacillus that does not require a specific host plant. For example, Rhizobium japonicum fixes a fair amount of nitrogen, but only as nodules on the roots of alfalfa. We would like one that will fix an immense quantity of nitrogen anywhere, in any soil, on any crop."

Answer (score 3):

I think this story is from Analog in the '80s or '90s.

As I remember one character was behind the plot.  That character believed that high altitude people had been persecuted by low altitude people for centuries.

One claim the leader of the plot made was that the Spaniards who were with Pizzaro at Cajamarca were the ancestors of the wealthy "40 families" of Peru.    That didn't seem correct to me, so I checked a book I remembered reading, *The Man of Cajamarca: A Social and Biographical Study of the First Conquerors of Peru*, James Lockhart, which was originally published in 1972.  Therefore I read it for the first time after 1972 and reread it years later after reading the story.

And when I reread it I saw that like I remembered only one or two of the 168 conquistadors remained in Peru as wealthy and respected members of society and became the ancestors of leading families in Peru.

Another non historical part of the story happened when the protagonist was informed that the object he was sitting on was the body of Atahuallpa, mummified in the traditional way by the priests at Cuzco, something which would never have happened in real life.

And I believe the genocidal project involved removing nitrogen from the air, not oxygen.

Comment: Although it appears to be correct information, this is really a comment since it does not provide an identification.